# Why did Debian install this Python3.9 stuff?

Tags: debian, apt, python

Normal Debian Sid here, I wonder why Apt installed some stuff apparently related to the next version of Python (as of August 3 2020)

```
$ locate -b python3.9
/usr/lib/python3.9
$ du -s /usr/lib/python3.9/*
756     /usr/lib/python3.9/distutils
72      /usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload
484     /usr/lib/python3.9/lib2to3
380     /usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter
$ for d in `ls -d /usr/lib/python3.9/*` ; do dpkg -S $d ; done
python3-distutils: /usr/lib/python3.9/distutils
python3-tk:amd64: /usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload
python3-lib2to3: /usr/lib/python3.9/lib2to3
python3-tk:amd64: /usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter
$
```

Answer (score 5):

These packages all come from [`python3-stdlib-extensions`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/python3-stdlib-extensions), which [added 3.9 versions a few weeks ago](https://salsa.debian.org/cpython-team/python3-stdlib/-/commit/94d208e8f3ac8b61b074488833a681d4f6225d23).

This is an early step in the transition to Python 3.9, and doesn’t have any effect on programs using Python 3.8 (the current default version in unstable).